# React Conditional rendring

Tags: reactjs

I am creating the main page for my frontend app using React.

I want it to direct the user to the login page if he is not already logged in, and direct him to another page if he is.
I'm checking if the browser knows the user using the function getCurrentUser ().

here is what I tried to do on the main page.

SignIn and Myprofile are React components that i want to render.

```
function App() {
  return (
  {if getCurrentUser()==null {return <SignIn/>} else return { <Myprofile/>}}
  )
```

this is the definition of getCurrentUser ():

```
const getCurrentUser = () => {
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
};
```

its looks like everything is working but all i see is blank page.
if i add a h1 tag for one of the options like here:

```
function App() {
  return (
  {if getCurrentUser()==null {return <SignIn/>} else return { 
   <div> 
   <h1>hello</h1> 
   <Myprofile/> 
   </div>}}
  )
```

I can see the H1 but not the other elements of these components.

how can I fix that?
thank you!

Comment: If you see the `h1` meaning that you have a problem with `Myprofile` component and maybe CSS, it has nothing to do with conditional rendering. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your `App` functional component doesn't have a valid return. It should be `return !getCurrentUser() ? <SignIn/> : <Myprofile/>;`. `if-else` isn't valid JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tertiary conditional rendering as it is simple and more readable.

```
function App() {
  return !getCurrentUser() ? <SignIn/> :  <Myprofile/>
}
```